# How to Mod-Rewrite underscores to dashes with up to 4 variables and new text?

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do I Mod-Rewrite underscores to dashes with 1 to 4 variables and new text?

**To change from this:**

```
https://example.com/Text_var1_var2_var3_var4.html
```

**To this:**

```
https://example.com/NewText-var1-var2-var3-var4.html
```

**I've tried this but it gives a 404 error:**

```
RewriteRule ^text_([a-zA-Z]+)_?([a-zA-Z]*)_?([a-zA-Z]*)_?\(*([a-zA-Z]*)\)*.html?$ newtext-$1-$2-$3-$4^.html
```

Comment: Presumably this should be a 3xx external redirect?

Comment: Yes it is to create a permanent redirect for external webpages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this should be an external redirect (in order to "correct" the URL), not an internal rewrite, as you appear to be trying to do?

Try it like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle from 1 to 4 "variables" and "newtext"
RewriteRule ^text_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html$ /newtext-$1.html [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^text_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html$ /newtext-$1-$2.html [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^text_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html$ /newtext-$1-$2-$3.html [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^text_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html$ /newtext-$1-$2-$3-$4.html [R=302,L]
```

Each "variable" is limited to the characters `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9` (although you omitted digits in your example directive, your example URL does strictly contain digits and you've not stated otherwise).

You can do it more "dynamically" to avoid repeating `text` and `newtext` in each rule, but that would make it arguably more complex and there doesn't seem to be a need considering it would appear to be a static text replacement and a limited number of "variables".

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^text_([a-zA-Z]+)_?([a-zA-Z]*)_?([a-zA-Z]*)_?\(*([a-zA-Z]*)\)*.html?$ newtext-$1-$2-$3-$4^.html
> ```

This has a number of issues/anomalies:

- You have an erroneous `^` in the *substitution* string.
- You are trying to handle all 1 to 4 *variables* in a single directive. The problem here is that the number of hyphens in the *substitution* string is "fixed". So, if there was just one variable (eg. `/text_var.html`) then the resulting substitution would be `newtext-var---.html` (if not for the erroneous `^`) - which I'm sure is not the intention.
- You are allowing any number of *optional* parentheses surrounding the 4th "variable", but you make no mention of this in your requirements? eg. `/text_one_two_three_(((four).html` would be matched, but only `one`, `two`, `three` and `four` are captured.
- This is an internal rewrite, not an external redirect. So unless `/newtext-var1-var2-var3-var4.html` maps to a physical file then this requires further rewriting to be resolved correctly (which is unlikely to work).